# Filenames written to HDFS by spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

The question is regarding spark 1.6

When a dataframe is written to HDFS in `SaveMode.APPEND` mode, I want to know which files were created new.
A way to do this is to keep track of files in HDFS before and after job, is there a better way?

Also Map-Reduce prints job statistics at the end, do we have something similar for every spark action.

Comment: As an alternative you could introduce an artificial partition column with a constant value across all rows. As a value you could use a UTC timestamp. **df.write.mode(SaveMode.APPEND).partitionBy("_ARTIFICIAL_COLUMN").parquet(.....)**". this will not impact performance of the code, and all new files will be in a separate folder.

Comment: @alexeipab my usecase is different here. I want to add files to existing partition, and want to figure out the new files added. Data cannot be written to new partition.